# Fermat Auto Check Script

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to create a script which will automatically cycle through a set of numbers and check them against the Fermat counterexample. I already have a script which takes an input of numbers from the user and checks them against the counterexample. What I would like to do is to get this system to be automated and take numbers in a specific range check all the possible combinations of these numbers in the counterexample a**n+b**n=c**n where n>2. I was thinking of graphing the equation and having it run all the on that graph. if you have any other ideas for how to do this please help. I have already checked some other sources but can't get a real grasp on how to get a graph into the code.

```
def prompt_yesno(prompt):
   return input(prompt) in 'Yy'

def prompt_int(prompt, min=None):
    while True:
        try:
            ans = int(input(prompt))
            if min is None or min <= ans:
                return ans
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be an integer.")

def is_fermat_counterexample(a, b, c, n):
    return n > 2 and a**n + b**n == c**n

def fermat_demo():
    print("Let's see if Fermat was right.")
    print("He claims that a^n + b^n = c^n cannot be true for any n > 2.")
    a = prompt_int('Give a positive integer for "a": ', 1)
    b = prompt_int('Give a positive integer for "b": ', 1)
    c = prompt_int('Give a positive integer for "c": ', 1)
    n = prompt_int('Give an integer bigger than 2 for exponent "n": ', 3)
    print("Fermat was incorrect"
      if is_fermat_counterexample(a, b, c, n) else
      "No, that does not work!")

while True:
    fermat_demo()
    if not prompt_yesno("Would you like to try again?\n"
                    "Type 'Y' to continue and 'N' to exit: "):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to take range for a,b and n only and calculate c.
If range of a,b is [1 to X] and range of n is [3 to N] then call following method for every combination of (a, b, n) to find a counter example -

```
def is_fermat_counterexample(a, b, n):
    value = a**n + b**n
    c = value**(1/n)
    return (c.is_integer() and (int(c) > 0))
```